# Artifacts in shading do not understand how to fix

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials

[image]

Artifacts in shading and render view, do not understand how to fix tried to throw to another document blend. But artifacts still remain

Comment: With this object selected, if you go to the object data tab in the properties panel (on the right side, the little green triangle) and then scroll down to Geometry Data, does it say "Clear Custom Split Normals Data"? If so click that and see if it fixes it.